# Why my animation gets stuck sometimes in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, canvas, firefox4

I am trying to create an animation using HTML5 canvas and Javascript. Although it works perfectly in Google Chrome, but in Firefox this gets stuck sometimes.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UbTwh/ .

I guess this is performance issue. Am drawing and clearing the canvas in a wrong way?

Comment: You might want to try `requestAnimationFrame`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozRequestAnimationFrame.

Comment: What do you mean, "gets stuck?" It seems to run fine on FF4.0 in Win7 for me. Try commenting out all of your console.log statements too.

Comment: Works fine for me too, smooth, no halting and no juddering - FF4/Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: I have a core 2 duo with 4GB ram, but it is possible that my system might have slowed down a little, not so much as to cause this halting. Anyway since it is working fine you then I guess for quite a chunk of traffic will see this as intended. That's gud enough for me. This is only supposed to be shown when the page is loading.

Answer (score 1):

Runs fine for me; sounds like it's performance-related on your machine. What specs are you running? If your CPU is getting bogged down or Firefox is eating RAM, everything goes out the window in relation to stability; I've seen everything from DHTML to Flash freeze and die because of performance issues on the computer itself.

If you just want to boost performance on your local machine, I would refrain from clearing the entire picture for every frame. The vast majority of your circles do not need to be redrawn; even though it's easier, calling clear() every frame significantly increases your performance cost. Plus, it's a nice exercise. :)

Comment: Yes I can do that. I was thinking of that, didn't try. Anyway push that also.